Python FastAPI: Request and Response instances auto creation
I have this code snippet.
from fastapi import Request, Response

my_api = FastAPI()

@my_api.get("/get_items")
async def get_items(req : Request, res : Response):
     json_data = await req.josn()
     res.status_code = 200
     ....
     ....
     return res

The above code works fine!!
In the above method, there are two parameters defined, req and res. Their type is Request and Response and they are imported from fastapi package.
json data is queried using json method on req object and ststus_code attribute is set on res object.
All these happen without instances of them being created.
My question is: when this route is called (eg: http://localhost:8000/get_items), how these parameters are initialised?
Basically these are classes and instances of them are created and passed to them from somewhere; but I am not sure the place.

FastAPI resolves dependencies using quite a bit of magic - i.e. FastAPI resolves these parameters dynamically for each request based on the associated typing information, and then calls the endpoint function with these parameters filled in. You can start tracing the magic in the dependencies module in FastAPI: https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/blob/3425c834cc113060d00b8a295d3456eb306a109d/fastapi/dependencies/utils.py#L524

I'd also like to note that you usually shouldn't have to call json() on the request, but instead use a pydantic model that matches the expected JSON data. And you shouldn't really have to modify the Response yourself either, but instead either return just a dict (which will be serialized as json) and use a Pydantic response_model to select fields and their types (which also supports using a sqlalchemy model or similar with attributes with the correct configuration), or use one of the other pre-created response classes (file/etc.)

And to explain: the reason for doing that is that it'll validate your data appropriately automagically, so you save a lot of boiler plate / validation code, and it also lets you automagically generate the correct documentation under /docs.
